# Change the error message in inserting a url with $ form -> $ filed

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I want to change the error message that comes out when you enter a url wrong. I show you what I mean:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueirY.png)

The message must become: **Inserisci un URL valido. Es: https://www.google.it**

I am modifying the view.php generated automatically by gii. Here is the code:

`<?= $form->field($model, 'link')->input('url')?>`

This is the function I use to enter a valid url.

Comment: I did it: `<?= $form->field($model, 'link')->input('url', ['oninvalid'=>"this.setCustomValidity('Inserisci un link funzionante. Es: https://www.google.it')"])?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the rules in your model for the attribute `link` using an [inline validator](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#creating-validators):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['link'], 'required'],
        ['link', function ($attribute, $params, $validator) {
            // Check validity of attribute
            if ($this->$attribute != ...) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Inserisci un URL valido. Es: https://www.google.it');
            }
        }],    
    ];
}
```

When checking the validity of the `$link` attribute, you also can use the [Yii2 UrlValidator](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-urlvalidator).